# Python Tkinter Entry > insert instead of selected, show cursor position

Tags: python, string, lambda, tkinter, tkinter-entry

For example I have string ABCDEFG but selected only "BCD" in Entry. How to replace selected text with lambda function?

Second question is about showing cursor. I have Entry with 20 width and `justify=RIGHT`. I want to show last characters. For example AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDDEEEEEFFFFF, i see the "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDDEE" but i need "CCCCDDDDDEEEEEFFFFF"

Example of my inset code and Entry init

```
vstup = Entry(group, textvariable=vstupObsah,font='Verdana 14', width=37,justify=RIGHT)

Button(keys, text=u"sin()",font='Verdana 15',width=5,height=1,padx=7,pady=1, command=lambda: vstup.insert(INSERT,"sin(")).grid(row=1, column=0,rowspan=1, padx=6, pady=5)
```

Comment: have you read the Entry widget documentation to know what commands are available to you? Have you tried any of those commands? Knowing what you've tried will help us understand what you are struggling with. Also, why does the replace command have to use lambda? What's wrong with using a named function?

Comment: thank you, your idea gave me on the right way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I´ve solved it :-)

```
def put_sel(value):
    try:
        vstup.delete("sel.first","sel.last")
    except:
        pass
    vstup.insert(INSERT,value)
    vstup.xview(INSERT)
```